# fullcalendar initdate not working how can I go/scroll to todays date in timeline?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I use timeline and initalView with resourceTimelineYear and I give todays date but he starts at january although we have may.

I tried both solutions:

```
initialDate="2023-05-05"
initialDate={new Date()}
```

but without success.

code:

```
        <FullCalendar 
          ref={ref}
          schedulerLicenseKey="xxx" 
          plugins={[ resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin, scrollGrid ]}
          initialView='resourceTimelineYear'
          initialDate="2023-05-05"
          locale='de'
          stickyHeaderDates
          height='auto'
          stickyFooterScrollbar
          dragScroll
          aspectRatio={0.8}
          editable={false}
          eventDragStop={(e) => console.log(e)}
          eventClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
          selectable={true}
          unselect={(e) => console.log(e)}
          selectMirror={true}
          resources={[
            { id: 'a', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium A' },
            { id: 'b', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium B' },
            { id: 'c', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium C' },
            { id: 'd', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium D' },
            { id: 'e', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium E' },
          ]}
          eventChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
          
          events={[
            {
              title: "sdaas",
              start: "2023-01-01",
              end: "2023-01-05",
              resourceId: 'a',
            },
          ]}
          scrollTime='00:00'
          resourceGroupField='building'
        />
```